# The correct way of installing pip on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

I tried quite some approaches [including this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows).

However, it all ends up with

```sh
pip -v
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python39\python.exe"  
"C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" -v': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

```sh
> python
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What's the correct and tested way of installing pip on a Windows 10 machine?

Comment: If you have python 3.91, how did you install it? Most installations come with pip by default.

Comment: I think you have installed pip, but it's pip3.
try doing the following:
py -m pip --version

Comment: clone https://github.com/pypa/pip , and then go inside directory and run `python get-pip.py` it will do it's job, more info [install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pip` directly from within the `python` you called by just placing `-m` after it followed by `pip` i.e
`python -m pip install desire+library`

Comment: That still won't work if pip isn't installed anywhere. It still calls the same executable, and if it isn't there, pip just can't run.

Comment: By default, `pip` comes with the newer version of `Python`.@OctopuSS7

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't got pip with your python installations (check with `python3 -m pip --version`), then you will need to download a file called `get-pip.py`. Simplest way is to use `curl`, but you can also just download it from `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`, and run it with python. If not, run the following:

`C:\> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

`C:\> python3 get-pip.py`

(All documented here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

(The lastest version will automatically be downloaded)

Comment: However, the correct and tested way would be to have installed it during python installation, as this is a little more difficult, because you may have quite a few python installations.